# Difference between creating a Class regularly and using Class.new

Tags: ruby

I can create a class using a constant name with `class` keyword:

```
class MyClass1; end
```

I can also create a class with `Class.new` and assign that to a constant or a variable:

```
MyClass2 = Class.new do; end
myClass3 = Class.new do; end
```

but I cannot create a class using `class` keyword with a name that begins in lowercase:

```
class myclass4; end # => Error
```

Is there a fundamental difference between these four? Isn't `myclass3` a regular class?

Answer (score 1):

- The first method (`class MyClass; end`) is an explicit part of the language syntax (in that `class` is a keyword), and the class’s name must be a constant.
- The second method (`Class.new`) is just a normal method call, and returns an anonymous instance of Class. This anonymous instance can then be treated like any other object.

Other than that, *there are no differences between the two methods*. Note that you can still assign the first type into a non-constant, but it must also first be assigned into a constant:

```
class MyClass; end
my_class = MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Andrew Marshall's answer, but also different.

---

Think of it this way:

1. The `class Foo ...` syntax does more than defining a class; in addition to defining a class, it necessarily names it when called for the first time, and a class name must be a constant. Note that, in principle, a class can be nameless (see #3).
2. On the other hand, assignment can be done to a variable or a constant. There is no restriction to that.
3. A purer way to create a class is to use `Class.new`. Using this syntax, you do not have to name it. So it is okay to assign it to a variable:

   ```
   foo = Class.new
   # => #<Class:0x007f36b23159a8>
   ```

   Only when it is assigned to a constant for the first time does it get named:

   ```
   Foo = foo
   # => Foo
   ```

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the formatting. I still don't know how to put code blocks within bullets. But I will see how you did it.

Comment: It’s unfortunately un-obvious and the formatting buttons get it wrong: you have to double-indent the code blocks (8 spaces instead of 4).

Comment: I see. I will try that from the next time.